# Finding a Special Independent Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For each $a \in R$, the set $\mathbb{Q}[a] =\{p(a)\: |\: p(X) ∈ \mathbb{Q}[X]\:\}$ is a subspace of $ \mathbb{R}$, considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Find all pairs $(a, b)$ of real numbers $a \neq b$ satisfying the condition that the set $\{\mathbb{Q}[a],\mathbb{Q}[b]\}$ is independent over
$\mathbb{Q}$.

Would be the answer a set $S=\{(a,b)|\:\:a\:is \:an \:algebraic \:\:number ,\:\:b\:\:is\:a\:\:transcendental\:\:number \}$?

Comment: If $S = \lbrace (a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\rbrace$, what happens if you choose the pair $(\pi,\pi^2)$? Specifically, something like $\pi^2+4\pi^4+6\pi^6$ should be in both $\mathbb Q[\pi],\mathbb Q[\pi^2]$.

Comment: What means independent ? That $\mathbb{Q}[a] \cap \mathbb{Q}[b] = \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 a collection $\{W_h|h\in \Omega \}$ of subspaces of $V$ is independent if and only if it satisfies the follwing condition: if $\Lambda$ is a finite subset of $\Omega$ and if choose elements $w_h\in W_h$ for all $h\in \Lambda$, then $\Sigma_{h\in \Lambda}w_h=0_V$ when and only when $w_h=0_V $ for each $h\in \Lambda$.

Comment: @Parisina Here it means $(\mathbb{Q}[a]\setminus \mathbb{Q}) \cap \mathbb{Q}[b] = \{0\}$